# No envía el email para confirmar usuario registrado

Tags: python, django

Tras rellenar el formulario de registro de nuevo usuario debería enviar un email de confirmación para que al clicar el usuario se confirme el registro de usuario (típico) pero devuelve un error. El servidor de correo está bien configurado ya que por ejemplo la recuperación de password la hace bien enviando un email al usuario. El problema está al confirmar el registros de usuario.

Views.py

```
class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/user_registration.html'
    model = User
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home_app:home')

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', None)
        user = User.objects.filter(email__exact=email).last()
        if True:
            token = get_random_string(length=34)
            url_activation = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000{path}'.format(domain=settings.BASE_URL,path=reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login', kwargs={'email': email}))
            context = {'url_activation': url_activation, 'user': user.username, 'date': now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}
            html_message = render_to_string('users/email_confirm_new_user.html', context)
            plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
            texto_email=send_mail(subject='Confirmar nuevo usuario', message=plain_message, from_email='info@prueba.com',
                          recipient_list=[email], html_message=html_message)
            if texto_email:
                user_token = TokenToUser(user=user, token=token, date=now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                user_token.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Email enviado.')
            else:
                messages.error(request, '¡ups! Algo no ha ido bien.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'El email no existe, debe registrarse como nuevo usuario.')
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login'))
```

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Urls:

```
app_name = 'users_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login',
        views.UserLoginView.as_view(),
        name='user-login',
    ),
    path('user_registration/',
        views.UserRegistrationView.as_view(),
        name='user-registration',
    ),
    path('user_logout/',
        views.UserLogoutView.as_view(),
        name='user-logout',
    ),
    path('user_reset/',
        views.UserResetView.as_view(),
        name='user-reset',
    ),
    path('user_newPassword/<str:token>',
        views.CreateNewPasswordView.as_view(),
        name='user_newPassword',
    ),
    path('user_contact',
        views.contact_form,
        name='contact',
    ),
]
```

Tras hacer los cambios propuestos por (Kevin Ramirez Zavalza), devulve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde faltaría /?

Answer (score 0):

Tu error se encuentra en esta linea:

```
url_activation = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000{path}'.format(domain=settings.BASE_URL,path=reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login', kwargs={'email': email}))
```

Específicamente en esta parte:

```
reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login', kwargs={'email': email}
```

El error sucede por que le estas pasando a la url 'users_app:user-login' el kwarg email, y si observas a detalle en tu urls.py, la url no acepta un parametro llamado email:

```
path('login',
        views.UserLoginView.as_view(),
        name='user-login',
    ),
```

Por lo que veo supongo estas generando un link para activar la cuenta, no se como tengas tu view para activar la cuenta ni tu url, pero la url debería de ser algo así:

```
path('activar/<str:token>/',
            views.ViewActivar.as_view(),
            name='user-activar',
        ),
```

Y tendrías que corregir esta parte para que al hacer el reverse haga match con la url de arriba:

```
token = get_random_string(length=34)
url_activation = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000{path}'.format(domain=settings.BASE_URL,path=reverse_lazy('users_app:user-activar', kwargs={'token': token}))
```

Si te fue útil esta respuesta márcala como aceptada para personas que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: Gracias Kevin, tras hacer el cambio que propones, me devuelve el error que he añadido seguido a mi consulta.

Comment: Hola, podrías añadir la captura completa del error para ver en qué línea o en dónde se produce la excepción